# Forcing the paragraph placement

Tags: positioning, paragraphs, letters

I want to write a letter, so I began to write it. In order to write other letters I want the opening sentence to be placed at the same location on the page.

Indeed, this is what my letter looks like:

```
My name
My address

                                      The name of the company
                                      Their address


The opening sentence
```

In fact I want the opening sentence at the same location, no matter how long the length of the "company address" is.

How can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us the code of your document?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using package `textpos`.

Then you can define the your name and address in one block, the company infos in another block, and finally the opening sentence in one other block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{30mm}{30mm} % start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
My Name\\
My Address
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{2}(3,1)
Company Name\\
Company Address
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{3}(0,2)
The opening sentence
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]